# How to create rotating, artificial dipoles?

Tags: electrical-engineering

The electromagnetic field can be thought of as a superposition of light waves.

I am attempting a physical Fourier Transform - i.e. take simple plane waves of the electromagnetic field (a.k.a. light) and recreate basic fields by superposing the plane waves correctly.

My background is in theoretical physics and so I have little to no knowledge of applications. I know that the field of a rotating electric dipole becomes the simple plane wave I am looking for at large enough distances.

*So my question is*: How do I actually create a rotating dipole field, or do you have a better idea that suits the application?

I do not wish to use LED's due it's quantum nature and I wish to stay within the fuzziness of classical mechanics.

Comment: A rotating field (electric or magnetic) can be emulated by modulating crossed dipoles in quadrature. But your question is too vague to answer in its present state. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I wish to know how to create an electric dipole field and if there is a common way to do this so I can simply buy what I need. I want to rotate these dipoles because that gives rise to orthogonal electric and magnetic plane waves for large enough r, i.e. light, which is something I need for the design I am working on.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create light with [circular polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization)? The usual method is to combine a linear polarizer with a quarter-wave retarder -- [example here](http://www.apioptics.com/circular-polarizers.html)..

Comment: Are you familiar with [antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio))?

Comment: Dave Tweed: No any polarization will do. Simple plane waves would be preferable. Theoretical Electrodynamics taught me that if you take two oppositely charge particles, put them next to each other and rotate them that it will create light. The Electromagnetic field can be thought of as on big superposition of light waves and I am trying to make a physical Fourier Transform. I.e.see if I can take light and recreate simple Electromagnetic fields.

Comment: Chris Mueller: I had to build a radio in my first year but the rest of my education was all about theory (mostly quantum mechanics) so we barely spent any time on applications. Thank you for the link. I had no idea an antenna emulated a rotating dipole (very fascinating). 

However if I were to make an array of antennae (to superpose the waves) wouldn't the induction current cause for significant perturbations? Do you think I should then use insulating material to manage all the interference or do you know of other ways of making a rotating dipole field?

Comment: You keep saying "The electromagnetic field can be thought of as a big superposition of light waves" - Visible light is a *subset* of the electromagnetic *spectrum*. The Fourier transform converts between the time and frequency domains. I can't tell if you're trying to "play" a bunch of frequencies to recreate a signal or trying to get a signal to "excite" a bunch of (resonators?), but either way you need a set of "frequencies". You can do this with any form of colored light as colored light is actually at different frequencies. You can do this with LED's or with color filters.

Comment: FYI - I'm using a physical Fourier transform device right now. By putting three different frequency discrete light sources very close together; red, green, and blue; the relative intensities are varied to emulate a large variety of frequencies across the visible spectrum. It's an LCD color monitor. I'm not sure what you're trying to do that's different than this.